# Does ADL work with named lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, argument-dependent-lookup

Say I have a class and a named lambda in one namespace.

```
namespace bla {
    class X { /* ... */ };
    static auto lambda = []( X param ){ /* ... */ };
}
```

This lambda is almost equivalent to a function that has been declared inline. But can I call that lambda from another unrelated namespace without mentioning the namespace `bla` using ADL (argument dependent lookup, also called Koenig lookup)?

```
namespace blub {
    void f() {
        bla::X x;
        lambda( x ); // Does this compile?
    }
}
```

Comment: @jrok: No, a lambda and the polymophic function wrapper `std::function` are completely orthogonal and seperate concepts.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm being silly. It's 33C in shade here :)

Comment: @Andy: No it isn't. That proposal covers lambda objects themselves at function scope being passed as ADL arguments, not ADL for calling such a lambda.

Comment: Since this is a comment on all of the answers (or my comments to all of the answers), I'll put it here: I've found the text which limits ADL to functions and function templates.  So my comments are wrong, and I appologize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lambda is not a function, but an object that can be called like a function. As such, it doesn't get the function-treatment and its invocation is not subject to ADL.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Whether a name is subject to ADL or not depends on the syntax at the point it is used.  If the syntax is that of a function call, ADL kicks in.  (On the other hand, ADL can never find a class member.  Period.  Regardless of its type.)

Comment: My previous comment is completely wrong, but the wording used is still misleading.  ADL kicks in any time there is an expression with function call syntax.  But ADL will only "find" functions and function templates.

Answer (score 3):

A lambda is really an object, so the question really boils down to:

> Does ADL work for objects?

And the obvious answer is that it doesn't, ADL will only add *functions* to the set of candidates for overload resolution. Also note that if regular lookup finds anything other than a function, then ADL will not add any candidates to the overload resolution set.

```
namespace A {
   struct S { operator int() const { return 0; } };
   void f(S const &) { std::cout << "A::f\n"; }
}
auto f = [](int) { std::cout << "lambda\n"; }
namespace B {
   void test() {
      ::A::S s;
      f(s);      // prints lambda
   }
}
```

While `A::f` is a better match to the call than `::f`, because `::f` is found by lookup *and it is not a function*, ADL won't bring any other functions into the picture.

Comment: This is fundamentally incorrect.  ADL involves name lookup, and is independent of the entity the name is bound to.  ADL is _triggered_, at the call site, by the fact that the expression has function call syntax.  But ADL doesn't trigger _if_ the unqualified name lookup finds a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template.  (I've simplified a little, but that's the relevant part here.)

Comment: My previous comment is completely wrong, and David is (almost) right.  (I say almost, because ADL will also find function templates, not just functions.)  And my comment concerning his example still holds---in this case, there is no ADL, because a non-function was found during unqualified name lookup.  These are two separate issues.